# 'Gunning' means in the context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Australian John Landy, one of Bannister’s rivals also **gunning** to break the four-minute barrier, took more than a second off the Briton’s time in Turku, Finland, a few weeks later.
>
> [The source](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/06/sport/running-four-minute-mile-spt-intl/index.html)

It seems to me that 'gunning' here refers to the gunshot by the judge to start a running. But I might be wrong. Can anyone help with the meaning of 'gunning' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some specialised senses of the participle "gunning".

Cambridge dictionary has

> Be gunning for something
>
> to make a great effort to get or win something.

It is marked as *US informal*.

There is a related sense, "Be gunning for someone", meaning "give enthusiastic support".

I can't find "gunning to do something" in the usual dictionaries,  but it is clear that the idiomatic sense of "make a great effort" is intended.

Comment: +1 And "gunning for someone" can also mean *looking for someone in order to hurt or kill them*. Some quotes: "*... received a phone call 'telling me to be careful if I went into town as some of the staff were gunning for me' *", "*Kyle wasn't exactly gunning for the marine, but he would never be one of Kenn's many supporters*" (Kenn is the marine).